# local host forbidden apache2

Tags: apache2

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 15 2013 14:02:11

> My ERROR:

[image]

```
/var/www$ ls -l

total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root   23 جون   18 09:08 1.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rehan rehan   0 جون   18 09:13 httpd.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 rehan rehan 138 جون   15 12:18 IndexFile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 rehan rehan 177 جون   15 12:18 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 rehan rehan  43 جون   15 12:18 MetaFile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 rehan rehan 650 جون   15 12:18 p1.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 rehan rehan 261 جون   15 12:18 p2.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 rehan rehan 870 جون   15 12:18 p3.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 rehan rehan  89 جون   15 12:18 processsearch.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 rehan rehan 150 جون   15 12:18 searchengine.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal. Do the command :

> sudo nautilus

Go to **/var**. Right click on **www** folder and choose the option **properties**.
On the tab **permissions** change all folder access to **Access Files** or **Create and Delete Files**.
[image: Permission Tab]